# Why are my html5 labels not displaying in Live Web Preview?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, forms

I added this (taken straight from a book, "HTML5 24-Hour Trainer") to Default.aspx in an asp.net web project:

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal details</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="Name"> Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="Name"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Email"> Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="Email"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Tel"> Telephone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="tel" id="Tel"/>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </form>
```

The labels ("Name:", "Email:", and "Telephone:") are not displaying next to the text input controls (edit boxes) - or anywhere else (visible to me) for that matter if I select "Live Web Preview" (Ctrl+Alt+Enter). However, if I select View In Browser (Ctrl+Shift+W), I can see the labels.

And if I look at the page in any of my three options (Google Chrome, Internal Web Browser, or Internet Explorer), it works fine; it is *only* the Live Web Preview that is busted.

So the question is, why are the labels invisible with "Live Web Preview"? But I guess I'll just avoid that viewing option; no big deal.

Comment: I don't see any problem here - http://jsfiddle.net/gPugV/

Comment: Works fine for me. You probably have some css affecting it.

Comment: i try the same.. but it displays fine for me..

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post after realizing it *does* work except for with "Live Web Preview"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried the exact same thing and it works as expected. I guess it's a local issue. Need more info.